# how to fix .htaccess - redirect http://408.111.1111.domain.us/ to http://domain.us/index.php?w=408.111.1111

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite

We want to use mod_rewrite and .htaccess to do a redirect.  How do we redirect `http://408.111.1111.domain.us/` and `www.408.111.1111.domain.us/` to `http://domain.us/index.php?w=408.111.1111`  ?  If the original URL has a dash in place of the periods, or no periods in front of '.domain.us', it works fine.  Wildcard domains work fine.

Here is our `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +Followsymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*/images/.*$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !^.*/uploads/.*$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<>%{REQUEST_URI} ^([^.]+)\.rmwy\.us(:80)?<>/([^/]*) [NC]
RewriteCond %1<>%3 !^(.*)<>\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule   ^(.*)$ - [E=BLOGUSER:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^$ /index.php?w=%1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^page([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?w=%1&page=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profiles/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /profile.php?u=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^profiles/?$ /profile.php [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^albums/([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /album.php?u=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1&y=$1&m=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive\.php/(.*)/(.*)/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1&y=$1&m=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive/(.*)/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1&y=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive\.php/(.*)/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1&y=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^archive\.php/([^/]+)?$ /archive.php?w=%1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^friends/([^/]+)?$ /friends.php?w=%1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^friends\.php/([^/]+)?$ /friends.php?w=%1$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/friends/page([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /friends.php?w=$1&page=$2$3 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+).html$ /entry.php?w=%1&e_id=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /entry.php?w=%1&e_id=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^&([^/]+)?$ /index.php?w=%1&$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?w=%1&category=$1$2 [L]
RewriteCond %{ENV:BLOGUSER} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/page([0-9]+)/([^/]+)?$ /index.php?w=%1&category=$1&page=$2$3 [L]
```

Comment: Seems a messy way, have you considered using rel canonical and noindex, follow metas on the pages? This way these types of pages will never be indexed by Google rewarding you the full amount for the master pages. Redirects are ideal for pages that have back links and you want to pass some juice. But I doubt people are backlinking to those urls etc and you just want Google not to find these pages which the noindex, and rel canonical is more than suitable - in fact it's better since Google dislikes lots of redirects due to people abusing it over the years. 404 is often better than 301 these days

Answer (score 1):

My poor eyes are too tired to read through your .htaccess file but regarding your basic request for code that rewrites xyz.domain.us to domain.us/index.php?w=xyz, it would look something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^domain\.us [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}          (www\.)?([0-9.]+)\.domain\.us
RewriteRule ^.*$                  http://domain.us/index.php?w=%2 [L,R=301]
```

You could then expand this to cater for different file paths (e.g. /friends/xyz) by using different RewriteRules.